# What is effect of "__callback" SAL annotation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, annotations, callback, static-analysis

While I certainly understand the purpose of buffer annotations, I can't see what kind of errors [__callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383701%28VS.85%29.aspx) detects.

Any ideas, examples?

Comment: Give an example of its use in a header.  __callback is nowhere to be found on the page you link to.

Comment: Fixed the link. I don't have any clues about __callback, hence the question.

Comment: I thought you would have seen it in the wild, prompting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you forget the parens on something that returns void* and *isn't* a callback, SAL can tell you about it.

Comment: Can you also provide warning number?